# Change default camera properties

Tags: android, camera

I want to take a picture from my application using

```
Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(camera, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

and send it to a webserver. But since the webserver compresses it to a **150x150 image** of **size not more than 50 kb**, I don't need to take some **3264x2448 image** of **size ~ 2 mb** because it takes hell lot of time to send transfer. I want to take a minimum sized image.

So, is there a way to ask the camera for a specific sized image?

I tried it by using the Camera API and changing its properties:

```
private Camera mCamera;

Camera.Size pictureSize = getSmallestPictureSize(mCamera
                .getParameters());
        if (pictureSize != null) {
            mCamera.getParameters().setPictureSize(pictureSize.width,
                    pictureSize.height);
        }

private Camera.Size getSmallestPictureSize(Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result = null;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes()) {
            if (result == null) {
                result = size;
            } else {
                int resultArea = result.width * result.height;
                int newArea = size.width * size.height;

                if (newArea < resultArea) {
                    result = size;
                }
            }
        }

        return (result);
}
```

The problem is I still get the Larger images. But that's not the Actual problem:

when I use a preview for this, its like this

[image]

Not allowing user to rotate the preview, zoom in/out etc..

Is there a way to use the actual camera preview with custom parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Some camera starting to take image in landscape mode some in portait mode. This can be fixed at sdk level, it will be a bit expensieve at runtime, for cpu, but can be done.

You need a smaller size:

-at sdk level implement a pipeline, where you will shrink the captured image to 10-15% of original one, it will drain the battery, but can be done.
- at ndk level you have to implement a custom driver for each supported camera...for this custom driver you will implement a custom software too and all is fine.

Comment: according to [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/blob/master/Camera/Picture/AndroidManifest.xml) commonsware demo. In the manifest the orientation is set to landscape. So doing that will restrict the user to take images only in landscape mode, if they take image in portrait mode, they might get a 90 degree rotated image. So, is there a way to allow user to change the camera preview as he/she likes

Comment: according to documentation the Java is platform independent also the Android is platform independent, but in practice it isn't. According to my contract with client / boss I  need to produce software which works well, without any bugs. The Video / Audio stuff it is (very) platform / device dependent: tested and works on 8 device, but the next 2 not. Myth of platform independent and according to documentations...